# Custom negative sign symbol in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, cell-format

Is it possible to make numbers in Excel cells to be displayed just as in General format, except for only one thing: another character (or several characters) in place of common minus sign? I.e. make −5 be rendered as “!5”, “minus 5”, ➖5 or even 5.

I look for a solution affecting only visible formatting of the numbers, but not their actual values, use in formulas, etc.

I have experimented with custom number formats like `#,##0` and so on, but they all lead to loss of “generality” of General format. In particular, the custom formats either include a decimal point into every number, even whole one, or don’t include it globally, even into fractional numbers.

Also, there is a setting of negative number sign deep inside in Control Panel, but it affects the whole user interface, and I need a solution for a particular Excel workbook.

I tried to make use of Conditional Formatting, but on this way, I came to a conglomeration of ugly crutches that hurt my feeling of conceptual integrity. Maybe it is possible to succeed with Conditional Formatting, but I don’t know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this Custom format:

```
General;"!"General;0
```

It will change the negative to `!`

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Ah, I was in Rome and did not noticed the Pope. :-)